# Hibernate Detached Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

I have a DetachedCriteria which I am using to search a table based on a name field. I want to make the search case-insensitive, and am wondering if there is a way to do this without using HQL. Something like:

```
private void searchByFullName(DetachedCriteria criteria, String searchCriteria) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("fullName", "%" + searchCriteria.toUpperCase() + "%"));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("fullName"));
}
```

But I want to make sure that it will ignore the case when it does the search, so the SQL it generates should look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ? LIKE toUpper(FULL_NAME);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is ilike

http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)